# AssertJ multidimensional arrays assertion (deep equals)

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, assertj, deepequals

Is there any option in *AssertJ* to make deep assertion of 2-d (N-d) arrays? Pretty much the same as `java.util.Arrays#deepEquals()` does but with assertion exception and prettified fail message like "element arr1[i][j] expected to be X, but was Y"

Here i found only 1d arrays assertions:

https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-examples/blob/master/assertions-examples/src/test/java/org/assertj/examples/ArrayAssertionsExamples.java

Comment: waiting for https://stackoverflow.com/users/1348834/joel-costigliola :)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no such feature in AssertJ but contributions are welcome.
I voted for Kevin Welker suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see one, but you could write your own with: [AbstractAssert](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-custom-assertions.html), or using a Comparator and the [usingComparator](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core-8/api/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractAssert.html#usingComparator-java.util.Comparator-) method

Answer (score 1):

There is a `isDeepEqualTo()` method available [since 3.17.0](https://assertj.github.io/doc/#assertj-core-3-17-0-release-notes).
Check out [Array2DAssertionsExamples](https://github.com/assertj/assertj-examples/blob/0868b5d724374ca0eb3f6c2456b27acd5ac740e0/assertions-examples/src/test/java/org/assertj/examples/Array2DAssertionsExamples.java)